# Is this true?: converging sequence question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let X be a metric space, and let A ⊂ X. Suppose that {pn} is a sequence in A
which converges to some point p ∈ X. True or false: i) p ∈ A′ (limit points of A)
(ii) p ∈ closure(A)

These are both true, right? And if (i) is true isn't (ii) always true (because closure(A)=A union A')

Comment: Is $E$ the same as $A$?

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited it

Comment: Consider a sequence such that $p_n = p$ for all $n$. Then $p$ need not be a limit point of $A$.

Comment: You're correct that $p\in E'$ implies $p$ is in the closure of $E$, since the closure of $E$ is $E\cup E'$.

Comment: Bungo, isn't the limit of that sequence just p? Which is in A?

Comment: Yes, it's in $A$ but not necessarily in $A'$, because $p$ could be an isolated point of $A$. But it is true that $p \in \text{closure}(A)$. So (ii) is true, but (i) need not be.

Comment: Then would pn still be convergent?

Comment: Also how did you think of that so fast?

Comment: Sure, if $p_n = p$ for all $n$ then $p_n$ converges to $p$. I'll go ahead and write this up as an answer to make it more coherent.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand the idea now. But I wouldn't have come up with that on my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $p_n = p$ for all $n$. Then $p_n$ converges to $p$, but $p$ might not be a limit point of $A$. It might be an isolated point of $A$.

To give a concrete example, suppose that $A = \{0\} \cup [1,2]$ and $p_n = 0$ for all $n$. Then $p_n \rightarrow 0$ but $0$ is not a limit point of $A$.

What you can say for sure is that if $p_n \in A$ and $p_n \rightarrow p$, then $p$ is either an isolated point of $A$ or a limit point of $A$. In either case, $p \in \text{closure}(A)$ since $\text{closure}(A) = A \cup A'$ and every isolated point of $A$ is contained in $A$.

Referring to your problem statement, (i) implies (ii) but (ii) does not imply (i). And $p_n \rightarrow p$ implies (ii) but not necssarily (i).

Note that a point $x \in X$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ distinct from $x$. This in fact is equivalent to the condition that every neighborhood of $x$ contains *infinitely many* elements of $A$. Another equivalent condition is that there exists a sequence $x_n \in A$ of *distinct values* (no repeats) which converges to $x$.

Given any set $A$, every element of $A$ is either an isolated point of $A$ or a limit point of $A$. Also, $A$ contains all of its isolated points but it need not contain all of its limit points.

Comment: @user1961722: I added some more information, hopefully it will be helpful.

Comment: very helpful. thanks again

Comment: Hi Bungo, I noticed a theorem in my textbook that says that a sequence pn converges to a limit p if and only if every neighborhood of p contains pn for all but finitely many n. Does this rule out that p could be an isolated point?

Comment: @user1961722: Consider again the case where $p_n = p$ for all $n$. Then every neighborhood of $p$ contains *every* $p_n$, but $p$ may still be an isolated point. Note the distinction: "contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$" doesn't necessarily imply "contains infinitely many points of $A$", because some (or in the $p_n = p$ example, all) of the $p_n$'s may be repeats.